# Moving a .Net website from IIS 6 - 7.5 (404.0 error)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

I'm getting the following error after migrating an app built on II6 to IIS 7.5

- Module   IIS Web Core Notification
- MapRequestHandler Handler    StaticFile
- Error Code   0x80070002

On the IIS 7.5 side, I have a wildcard script map setup to:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

The application pool is setup to use classic mode and .Net 2.

The URL I am working with would looking something like this:

```
http://fb.domain.com/ryanqaaw/tab/
```

The wildcard map would handle the /ryanqaaw/tab/ as those folders to not exist in the root.

Any help or tips would be GREATLY appreciated!

---

*EDIT*:
Adding Failed Request Tracing shows this:

```
ModuleName="IIS Web Core", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The system cannot find the file specified.
(0x80070002)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

But I am not too sure what to make of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS 7.5 the configuration is far more simple, almost no configuration  required.

What I suggest is, create a new Web application project and make it run in IIS 7.5 and then change your application's config file to mirror the new one.

Instead of your wildcard handler use an integrated pipeline for your apppool and all should be fine.

Comment: I setup the app to use integrated pipeline but the error was still thrown. After adding the following to the web.config I was able to resolve it.  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True" >

Answer (score 0):

Start IIS Manager and click on the server name. Double click on the option [ISAPI and CGI restrictions]. See if ASP.net v2.0 is enabled or not.

Comment: It is enabled - other ASP.NET pages run without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the wildcard mapping in the Handler Mappings list so that it comes before the StaticFile handler (clicking on "View Ordered List..." link in the actions pane and use the Move Up/Down options)